# require('file.json') doesn't work in webpack

Tags: json, node.js, webpack

I've a JSON file which I want to load in a Typescript class. Normally a syntax for that is

```
let json = require('file.json');
// Use of json file in TS class
```

This works perfectly fine under normal circumstances. But when I try to compile entire code with webpack, code doesn't work. I see the output code is replaced with following

```
var json = __webpack_require__(2);
```

This doesn't make much sense. Can somebody tell me what's going on under the hood and how to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you try `let json = require('./file.json');`? not sure that's the case, but...

Comment: Yeah I tried that. And that's what very first line of my code in this question is as well.

Comment: missing the `./`. I'm not expert, but using the require without the `./` means loading a file from the system core and not a local file...

Comment: I assure you path is correct. I've tested this without webpack and code works. Only when I compile with webpack, I get this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure WebPack to load JSON files.

https://github.com/webpack/json-loader

Comment: It's not relevant anymore, as it's work out of box starting webpack2 (https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#json-loader-is-not-required-anymore)